# Remove Facebook "friends" from Yahoo contacts

Tags: facebook, yahoo-mail, yahoo-messenger

A long time ago, I "linked" my Facebook account to my Yahoo mail account.

This resulted in all of my Facebook "friends" being added to my Yahoo contacts list.

Ordinarily, I guess this wouldn't be a problem, except when signing into Yahoo Messenger from my phone, in which case all of these people appear in my "contacts" list - and since I scarcely know most of them - they all appear in the contacts list as "offline", which is something of an irritation.

So, what do I need to do in Yahoo mail to remove all traces of my Facebook acount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to remove the binding to these services at any time.
>
> **Resolution**
>   To disconnect your Google or Facebook account from Yahoo!:
>
> 1. Sign in to the [Yahoo! Account Information Page](http://edit.yahoo.com/config/eval_profile)
> 2. On the sign in form, click Sign in with Google or **Sign in with Facebook**
> 3. Enter your Google or Facebook login information
> 4. Click **Manage Other Accounts to Sign-in**
> 5. Click **Remove** next to the Google or Facebook icon. A pop-up dialog box will open prompting you to confirm the action
> 6. When finished, click **Sign-out** at the top of the page

From [this Yahoo help page](http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?locale=en_US&page=content&y=PROD_ACCT&id=SLN2079&impressions=true).

Deleting the Facebook contacts from Yahoo is the same as for any other contact.

> Deleting Facebook contacts is the same as deleting any contact. There are no special measures that must be taken simply because the contact was imported from Facebook.
>
> You can see the contacts of your most recent Facebook import by going to **View** and selecting **View Last Import**.
>
> **Note:** If you have done multiple Facebook imports, you will only be able to see the results of your most recent Facebook contact imports.

From [How to delete Facebook contacts](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/news/social_networking/contactsimpexp-35.html).